# Need help for CompletableFuture or Callable Future

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice, completable-future, callable

I am facing issue for finding out which will be the best way for my below scenario.
I wanted to call 1 API by using multiple threads at a time and wanted to merge their response to make a list.

First i have created the threadPool and according to the size of the list m passing each record to the callable which is returning the API call response.

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(savedAssetparamList.size());
                List<Callable<DatapointLinkDTO>> allCalls = new ArrayList<>(savedAssetparamList.size());
                String finalToken = token;
                savedAssetparamList.stream().forEach(assetParam -> {
                    allCalls.add(Executors.callable(datapointLinkingHelper.postDataPoint(assetParam, mdspSubssationAssetId, finalToken, tenantId)));
                });
                executorService.invokeAll(allCalls);
    
   

     API call method.

    public DatapointLinkDTO postDataPoint(AssetParameter assetParameter, String mdspSubssationAssetId , String token, Long tenantId){
        

    DatapointLinkDTO datapointLinkDTO = new DatapointLinkDTO();

    //API call logic 

    return DatapointLinkDTO;

}
```

Comment: “I am facing issue” We’re sorry to hear that. Do you want to talk about it?

Comment: @Holger tried with Executors with Callable Job but the main thread was not waiting for all the child thread to complete. So took the Completable Future approach, its working.

Comment: This information: “but the main thread was not waiting for all the child thread to complete” should have been included in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CompletableFuture` already "wraps" an asynchronous computation that executes in another thread that you can await to get the result once it is ready. If you want to schedule the execution on a different executor than the default `ForkJoinPool` you can use

```
Executor executor = ...

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { /* Your code to call the api */}, executor);
```

To await for multiple completable future there is `CompletableFuture.allOf()` which accepts as many CompletableFutures as you want and awaits them. Unfortunately this function ignores the return values so you have to get them individually. A pseudo-working solution could be something like this:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)

List<CompletableFuture<Response>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    results.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { /* API Call */}, executor));
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(results.toArray());

results.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList());
```

PS. When you're dealing with I/O and not doing much computation it is better to use an unbounded (or bounded by a high number like 50 or more) cachedThreadPool executor that uses more threads but reuses the ones that are finished to better use resources